# How to run a string method on the slug_field value in a detail view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a page called food that gets a parameter called food url that needs to be 
with _ instead of spaces

```
url(r'^food/(?P<food_url>\w+)/$', Food.as_view()),
```

But the column in the model (name) uses spaces

```
#the view
class Food(DetailView):
    model = Food
    template_name = 'eat/food.html'
    slug_field = 'name'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'food_url'

#the model
class Food (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()

    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)


    calories = models.IntegerField()
    carbs = models.IntegerField()
    protein = models.IntegerField()
    fat = models.IntegerField()

    prepTime = models.IntegerField() #minutes

    LVL_CHOICES = (
    ('child','Child'),
    ('beginner','Beginner'),
    ('average','Average'),
    ('pro','Pro')
    )
    difficult_lvl = models.CharField(choices=LVL_CHOICES, max_length=8)

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['name']
    def get_url (self):
        return str(self.name).replace(' ','_')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Is there a way to run the replace method on the food_url value? Or any other solution

Thanks

Comment: Which column or the model? How is it look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this much more cleanly with a function based view, however since you're using a DetailView, I'd the quickest way would be to override the [`get_object`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2bcb8bfc8de5cd57ebb64b326cd7609aa0d8c1c7/django/views/generic/detail.py#L21) method. What I've done is basically take the passed in name value and convert the underscores into spaces. Obviously if you have names that contain spaces and underscores this won't work and you'll need to devise a new strategy to handle that.

That being said, I think you should create an actual slug field on that model and have it slugify the `name` field's value.

```
class Food(DetailView):
    model = Food
    template_name = 'eat/food.html'
    slug_field = 'name'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'food_url'


    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        """
        Returns the object the view is displaying.

        By default this requires `self.queryset` and a `pk` or `slug` argument
        in the URLconf, but subclasses can override this to return any object.
        """
        # Use a custom queryset if provided; this is required for subclasses
        # like DateDetailView
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()

        # Next, try looking up by primary key.
        pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg, None)
        slug = self.kwargs.get(self.slug_url_kwarg, None)
        if pk is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)

        # Next, try looking up by slug.
        elif slug is not None:

            ###########
            # Convert the underscores into spaces.
            ###########
            slug = slug.replace('_', ' ')
            ###########

            slug_field = self.get_slug_field()
            queryset = queryset.filter(**{slug_field: slug})

        # If none of those are defined, it's an error.
        else:
            raise AttributeError("Generic detail view %s must be called with "
                                 "either an object pk or a slug."
                                 % self.__class__.__name__)

        try:
            # Get the single item from the filtered queryset
            obj = queryset.get()
        except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404(_("No %(verbose_name)s found matching the query") %
                          {'verbose_name': queryset.model._meta.verbose_name})
        return obj
```